# How metamask popup opens whenever something has to do with metamask provider?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ether

I'm new to dapp development, I'm trying to build the similar wallet like metamask, I couldn't figure out how metamask popup opens whenever the code has to do something with metamask provider. Are they using any logic behind that?